# save cardview in sharedpreferences

Tags: android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, cardview

I have a recyclerview with card view. I want to change the image of one of them after click on it (It will go to another activity) but when I come back or after closing and reopening the app I don't want to change the image . I know that I should use Shared preferences but I'm totally confused and I don't know what should I do.
This is my custom recyclerview:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class LessonRecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LessonRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "LessonRecViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<Lesson> lessons = new ArrayList<>();
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private Context context;

    public LessonRecViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem_lesson_rec_view, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");

        holder.txtLessons.setText(lessons.get(position).getLessonNumber());


        final int imgSad = R.mipmap.sad;
        final int imgSmile = R.mipmap.smile;
        final int imgPlain = R.mipmap.plain;

        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imgPlain)
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int lessonId = lessons.get(position).getLessonId();
                switch (lessons.get(position).getLessonId()) {
                    case 1:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Lesson1Activity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Comming Soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lessons.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CardView cardView;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView txtLessons;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            txtLessons = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_lessons);

        }
    }

    public void setWords(ArrayList<Lesson> lessons) {
        this.lessons = lessons;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

Comment: You could try using `Room` database instead of using shared preferences.

Comment: Thank you so much, Room database helped me a lot.